# How do I print outputs for two inputs at the same time?

Tags: c

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int w,x,y,z;
  float v;
  printf("Enter the driver salary\n");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  printf("Enter the car mileage in km per litre\n");
  scanf("%d",&y);
  printf("Enter the cost of petrol per litre\n");
  scanf("%d",&z);
  printf("Enter the taxi fare for a km\n");
  scanf("%d",&w);
  printf("Enter the distance of travel\n");
  scanf("%f",&v);
  if(w==200 && y==10 && z==60 && x== 20 && v==10.5)
    printf("Minimal cost travel is by taxi\n");
  else
    printf("Minimal cost travel is by audi\n");
  return 0;
}
```

For two different set of values of inputs for `w`,`y`,`z`,`x`,`v`, I need to print both output statements at same time. I am getting first output, but how do I get two outputs at the same time?

Comment: Remove `else` and put it together under the `if`? Not really understanding the problem

Comment: Could you be more specific "two different set of values of inputs" is a bit vague and not helpful.   What usually helps is to provide desired output for given input, and then the actual output for that input.

Comment: Please try to explain your question a little more.

Comment: Do you want to input two times and then have output for these condition > @akku

Comment: i hav 2 set of inputs. first is w=200,y=10,z=60,x=20 and v=10.5. like i hav one more set of w,x,y,z&v values.. At same time for first input i need first output, and for 2nd input i shuld get 2nd output.

Comment: @akku , Will input be always entered two times?

Comment: `v==10.5` You shouldn't compare float numbers this way, it is not guaranteed to work. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output at same time have a flag array to store results.Also you may want to store the value of 10.5 in a float.**[Read more](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html)**.I added a few lines in your code check if it works :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{                    
  float l=10.5;             //to be safe about float rounding up
  int i,fl[2];              //stores results for output

  for(i=0;i<2;i++)          //add this
  {
    int w,x,y,z;
    float v;
    printf("Enter the driver salary\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter the car mileage in km per litre\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("Enter the cost of petrol per litre\n");
    scanf("%d",&z);
    printf("Enter the taxi fare for a km\n");
    scanf("%d",&w);
    printf("Enter the distance of travel\n");
    scanf("%f",&v);

    if(w==200 && y==10 && z==60 && x== 20 && v==l)   
      fl[i]=1;
    else  
      fl[i]=0;
  }
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    if(fl[i]==1) 
      printf("Case %d : Minimal cost travel is by taxi\n",i+1);
    if(fl[i]==0) 
      printf("Case %d : Minimal cost travel is by audi\n",i+1);
  } //close braces

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the core functionality in a `for/while` loop. I am going to suggest putting the core functionality in a function too.

```
void processInput()
{
   int w,x,y,z;
   float v;

   printf("Enter the driver salary\n");
   scanf("%d",&x);
   printf("Enter the car mileage in km per litre\n");
   scanf("%d",&y);
   printf("Enter the cost of petrol per litre\n");
   scanf("%d",&z);
   printf("Enter the taxi fare for a km\n");
   scanf("%d",&w);
   printf("Enter the distance of travel\n");
   scanf("%f",&v);
   if(w==200 && y==10 && z==60 && x== 20 && v==10.5)
      printf("Minimal cost travel is by taxi\n");
   else
      printf("Minimal cost travel is by audi\n");
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   for ( i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
   {
      processInput();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_i need to print both output statements at same time_" -- Not after each input

Comment: @CoolGuy, good point. I am going to give the OP some time to comment. If this is not what they are looking for, I will delete the answer.